# Magnetic field due to a current carrying circular arc at distance $x$ from its centre

Tags: magnetic-fields, geometry

I can't visualise how the component of $B$ field perpendicular to the arc's axis will be distributed for different current elements on the arc. [image]

Comment: Could you add a drawing, please? Or, could symmetry help you to simplify this to full 2π loop (in which case the problem is simple)?

Comment: OK .............

Answer (score -1):

As your problem lies in visualising, I hope you find this diagram useful(I tried to keep the shabbiness to a minimum):
[image]

Each element on the y-z plane would have a corresponding element that cancels out the component of the magnetic field perpendicular to the x-axis. What shall remain is the field along the x-axis. I wish I were able to depict this in the figure, but I didn't, lest it is hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for replying ...in the image it looks like u drew wrong direction for B field... Tell me if i am wrong

Comment: @ayush_rocks I don't think so. The bold blue lines show the field on the XY plane; the green ones show the field in the XZ plane. You can just imagine a straight line from the element to the point. This will give you the direction of the field.

Comment: I attached the image of the arc i am talking about..if possible then please derive a result for B field at x

Comment: The magnetic field of an element is perpendicular to the radius from the element to the point. Not along the radius. See Biot-Savart law.